# “A generic error occurred in GDI+” error where save image to file

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, rest, base64

I convert array byte of bitmap to encodedString and send with volley in android, and have no problem in these steps.

**android request code:**

```
 public static void uploadImageRequest(Bitmap bitmap, final Context context, final RequestListener requestListener) {
    Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<>();
    //convert Bitmat(image) to string.
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
    byte [] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
    final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);

    postParam.put("mac_address", AppUtil.getMacAddress(context));
    postParam.put("token", WorkData.getData("token", context));
    postParam.put("user_image" , imageString);


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Links.UPDATE_IMAGE_PROFILE_LINK, new JSONObject(postParam),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject json) {
                    try {
                        Message.messageText = json.getString("Message");
                        Message.messageType = json.getString("MessageType");
                        UserModel.isBlock = json.getBoolean("IsBlock");
                        UserModel.userProfileImageName = json.getString("ImageName");
                        requestListener.onResponse();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        requestListener.onError(e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            requestListener.onError(error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    requestListener.onRequest();
    requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

in server(asp.net) I convert base64string to array byte successfuly.

**my convert code**

```
var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(tblUserprofile.user_image);
```

and pass to the following method as parameter.

```
public static bool CreateImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(ms))
                {
                    image.Save("~/Content/UserProfiles/picture.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

when the code arrives to `image.Save(...);`, the following error occurs:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

Comment: this happen usually (for me) when the path of  the image is wrong

Comment: yes thanks, problem solved.

Comment: i post as answer .. so it can help other people ...if you can and want rate it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happen usually (for me) when the path of the image is wrong ... check yours images paths